# Python's BeautifulSoup find_all Method: Including and Excluding with RegEx in one search

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have a question regarding regular expressions and Python's (2.6) BeautifulSoup (4.4.0):

If I do this:

```
import re

re_expr = re.compile(r"(?!.*\bthis\b).*\bcol\b")

a = u"col this"
b = u"col"

print re.search(re_expr, a)
#None
print re.search(re_expr, b)
#<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0209EEC8>
```

I get a non hit in the first search, and a hit in the second search (as expected).

But if I do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """  <html>
        <table>
            <tr class="row">
                <td class="col this">value 1</td>
                <td class="col">value 2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </html>
"""

soup =  BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

t_row = soup.find('tr', class_='row')

print "t_row:\n", t_row
#<tr class="row">
#<td class="col this">value 1</td>
#<td class="col">value 2</td>
#</tr>

re_expr = re.compile(r"(?!.*\bthis\b).*\bcol\b")

t_tag = t_row.find_all('td', class_=re_expr)
print "t_tag:\n", t_tag
#[<td class="col this">value 1</td>, <td class="col">value 2</td>]
```

I get back both `td` tags, and not only the `td class="col"` as I would expect.

I know there are many workarounds for this, and I'm aware of them,
but I try to find out why this logic works different then I expect.

Why is the "fail if we can match 'this'" RegEx block not working here?
Using positiv (inclusion) and negativ (exclusion) hit RegEx in a `class_` search in BeautifulSoup would be great.

Has anybody a working example to do such a thing in ONE RegEx and the `.find` or `.find_all` method of BeautifulSoup?

Comment: seems to be related with the fact that bs4 puts the class content into a list, and does not handle it as string. Funny is that nevertheless this seems to be the case, you can search for full text "col this".